# Cannot Connect to localhost on SQL Server 2019 after Install

Tags: sql-server, localhost

SQL Server Management Studio is only letting me connect to `<PCNAME>\MSSQLSERVER`, but my work codebase is set up to connect to localhost (see below):

```
<property name="DatabaseConnectionString">Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DB_Name;User ID=User_Name;Password=Password</property>
```

The installation was fine. And my services ARE RUNNING! I've even restarted them a few times to be sure.

Does anyone know how to change the current set up Server to allow for local connection? I don't want to have to keep changing my codebase and DB scripts every time I need to connect to my databases.

This is what I want to be able to do to connect to the existing server:

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FNfI.png)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Have you tried using SQL Server 2019 Configuration Manager to create 32-bit and 64-bit aliases named `.`? I'm not sure it will accept `.` as a name, worth trying though.

Comment: what is returned when you execute  `select @@servername` ?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning you should be able to connect via Localhost by using ".", I've been doing it for years, im just unsure as to why its not working at this time.

Comment: @lptr when i run select @@servername i get <PCNAME>/MSSQLSERVER

Comment: worth a try: https://kohera.be/blog/sql-server/make-named-instance-look-like-default-instance/